# Deleting Hidden Columns from Libraries

Tags: delete, hidden

If I delete a hidden column without going into settings and unhiding it first will there be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

No it won't be, but if you are deleting hidden columns that SharePoint created, and not manually created, you will have quite a rough time trying to use SharePoint.

Comment: thank you. all of the hidden columns i have been deleting are manually created ones but my boss said that not unhiding them first may cause issues for the programmers (no idea what that means but thought i should investigate).

Comment: I would just let the programmers know which fields you are deleting first. They may be using or inheriting from hidden fields.